# How to calculate the sum of numbers when an upper limit value is defined?

Tags: .net, vb.net

For example how to calculate 1+2+3+4+5 when the user enters 5 or 1+2+3+4+5+6+7 when the user enters 7. I'm already planning on using an If statement to prevent the calculation of 0s and negative numbers...
I know this is pretty basic, but my tutor was unable to help me, and I would like to understand how the code behind this exercise works.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#/media/File:Animated_proof_for_the_formula_giving_the_sum_of_the_first_integers_1+2+...+n.gif

Comment: Your main issue is that you seem to be trying to get someone else to write the code for your homework for you and then working out how it works instead of working out what the code is actually supposed to do - the steps to get to the result, not just the result itself - and then working out how you might write code to do it. If you could do this task manually, i.e. with pen and paper, then you can work out an algorithm. That takes no programming experience. If you haven't done that then you haven't really tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to break this down into how you would do it on your own.

If I asked you to...

> Calculate the sum of all positive numbers up to `3`

...you would:

- Start with `1` and note it down.
- Proceed to `2`, add it to the previous result (`1 + 2`)
- Proceed to `3`, add it to the previous result (`1 + 2 + 3`)

The final result would be `6`.

To achieve this, you only needed one piece of information from me, the `upperLimit`. You then went through all the values between `1` and `upperLimit` and summed them up. This would be the equivalent of having one function, accepting `upperLimit` as a parameter, and then looping through all values in that range and adding them up:

```
Private Function SumUpTo(ByVal upperLimit As Integer) As Integer

    ' start at 0
    Dim result As Integer = 0

    ' go through all values between 1 and upperLimit
    For i = 1 To upperLimit
        ' add current value to result variable
        result = result + i
    Next

    Return result

End Function
```

Fortunately, there is a formula you can use to achieve the same result without going through all of the values, called the "*`n`th partial sum of the `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ⋯` infinite series*":

> `n * (n + 1) / 2` (ref: [1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ⋯](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF))

```
Private Function SumUpTo(ByVal upperLimit As Integer) As Integer

    Return upperLimit * (upperLimit + 1) / 2

End Function
```

I don't think your tutor is looking out for your mathematical knowledge but rather your algorithmic thinking, so I believe he will be looking for solutions like the first one, not the latter. Furthermore, you asked in the comments of another answer how to calculate `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * ⋯` instead; I wonder how easy it would be to take my first solution and literally tweak one character to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use Enumerable.Range ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range)) to generate a range of numbers from 1 to *n* and then Enumerable.Sum ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum)) to compute the sum of the collection.

Here is an example:

```vb
Private Function CalculateSum(upper As Integer) As Integer
    If (upper < 1) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Value cannot be less than 1", NameOf(upper))
    End If

    Return Enumerable.Range(1, upper).Sum()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will help?
[Stack post](https://superuser.com/questions/129511/how-can-i-calculate-the-sum-of-all-positive-integers-less-than-n)

You can use the function f(n) = (n+1)n/2

Comment: Thank you so much! I know it's kinda dumb, but it figures that there was a simple mathematical formula for adding the sum of numbers.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you think there is a mathematical formula that does the same, but for products? So, if a user entered 5, you would multiply 1*2*3*4*5?

Comment: @delta_stream I've edited the post, the mathematical equation was incorrect.

Comment: That's the factorial. You can use recursive function for this.